# Dolphin Emulator with Python

Tags: python

I wanted to ask if there is a way to communicate with the  dolphin emulator via python. Biz hawk has a Lua console but the script I'm trying to run is   in python. I'm also using Dolphin primarily because it has Super Smash Melee.

Comment: you are asking for some library / framework that lets python interact with dolphin.  Finding an off-site resource is explicitly marked as [off topic in the help center.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen IMHO He's only asking for a solution to a specific problem : communicating between dolphin and python. Feels fair enough to me.